# Wolox React Chat Widget does not hide buttons after quick button clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webchatjs

I am using [react-chat-widget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chat-widget) node module in my react project as a webchat, When I implemented setQuickButtons the buttons are not hiding even after button click. How can I make the buttons hidden once clicked?

In the handleQuickButtonClicked method I was setting quick buttons but those methods are staying on the screen even after clicking one of the buttons.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store';
import { Widget, addResponseMessage, addUserMessage, toggleWidget, setQuickButtons } from 'react-chat-widget';
import 'react-chat-widget/lib/styles.css';
import './index.css';
class Reactwidget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    handleNewUserMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
        if (message.includes('hi')) {
            addResponseMessage('Welcome to this test chatbot')

        }
    }
    handleQuickButtonClicked(message) {
        console.log('quick button clicked ' + message)
        if (message.includes('button') || message === 'button') {
            addUserMessage('you clicked button ' + message);
            addResponseMessage('hi')
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('didmount')
        addResponseMessage('hello there')
        toggleWidget();
        const buttonList = [{
            label: 'Button1',
            value: 'button1'
        },
        {
            label: 'Button2',
            value: 'button2'
        },
        {
            label: 'Button3',
            value: 'button3'
        }];
        setQuickButtons(buttonList)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Widget handleNewUserMessage={this.handleNewUserMessage}
                    title="Test webchat"
                    senderPlaceHolder="enter here"
                    showCloseButton={true}
                    showTimeStamp={true}
                    autofocus={true}
                    handleQuickButtonClicked={this.handleQuickButtonClicked}
                    toggleWidget={true}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Reactwidget />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: @Mellgood Added code as per your request

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty late but, try adding `setQuickButtons([]);` , which simply "replaces" the buttons with no buttons.